# Pausing SwiperJS autoplay when slider entered by keyboard tab, no mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, swiper.js, pause

I'm working an accessibility request and am trying to pause the slideshow when a user enters the slider by tabbing into it. It's already configured to pause on mouse hover and resume on mouse out, but it still slides when tabbed into any of the elements within the slider.

I checked the [API for SwiperJS](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api) and saw there's this:

```
swiper.autoplay.pause()
```

But how can I tell when the slider is the focus when a user navigates the website by keyboard and tabs into it?

I tried these jQuery snippets in the browser console, but they're not pausing the slideshow:

```
$(window).keyup(function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 9 && $('.carousel-wrapper:focus-within').length) {
        swiper.autoplay.pause();
    }
});

$(window).keyup(function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 9 && $('.carousel-wrapper:focus-within').length) {
        swiper.autoplay = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event on every tab-klick, check if focus is in swiper or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent on the swiper-element you want your focus

Comment: Tab keys are by far not the only way to focus an element on a web page. You should avoid using input events to assume focus movement. The `focusin` event should be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`focusin` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event) to pause autoplay.

There are different ways to focus an element, especially with assistive technology there might be no keyboard involved. It’s a dangerous assumption, to listen to keyboard events. Voice control software, for example, allows focusing elements simply by saying “Click next button”, which will also focus it.

Since it’s quite useless and unreliable to figure out which elements exactly can receive focus, you need an event that bubbles up to the slider element, which `focusin` does.

You’ll need to use the variable you used to store the reference to the Swiper instance when you initialised it.

```js
const swiper = new Swiper(…);
…
swiper.el.addEventListener("focusin", () => swiper.autoplay.pause());
```

The [Carousel pattern of the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/carousel/) also mentions the following concerning autoplay:

> If the carousel can automatically rotate, it also:
>
> - Has a button for stopping and restarting rotation. This is particularly important for supporting assistive technologies operating
>   in a mode that does not move either keyboard focus or the mouse.
> - Stops rotating when keyboard focus enters the carousel. It does not restart unless the user explicitly requests it to do so.
> - Stops rotating whenever the mouse is hovering over the carousel.

Comment: I've been experimenting with your above script in Chrome's console, but keep getting Uncaught ReferenceError: swiper is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(

Comment: Well `swiper` is what you referred to from the docs, but of course it depends [how you initialise it](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#initialize-swiper). You’ll need to use the name you gave to the variable during init `const myswiper = new Swiper(…);` will need `myswiper.el.addEventListener(`

Comment: This was the issue and your comment was the correct answer. If you convert it to an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Well you question was on how to pause the slider on focus, and the suggested way to do so in the question is problematic. It falls short of a good solution for accessibility. So I added the variable name part to my answer.

Comment: @linnse Hi again. If the variable name was the issue in your case and solved it, would you mind accepting the answer now?

Comment: I'm plugging this event listener on the afterInit event, that way we sure the swiper is initialized, and that elements are available :

`afterInit: function (swiper) {  swiper.el.addEventListener("focusin", (event) => {         swiper.autoplay.pause();  });`

Comment: Interesting. Is it necessary to wait for the elements? If there’s no element, nothing can receive and bubble focusin. The whole logic should be covered by the `focusin` event itself, or am I missing something?